# How to find the cumulative difference between two rows and display it accordingly in Azure Data Explorer

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I have requirement where I need to calculate the cumulative difference between each row in Azure Data Explorer.

Below is the sample data

```
ID | NAME    | Value
---+---------+------------- 
 1 | ABC     | 1987698.987
 2 | DEF     | 1987870.987
 3 | GHI     | 1987990.987
 4 | JKL     | 1988200.987
```

Expected result
Output:

```
ID | NAME  | Value       | Cumulative_difference
---+-------+-------------+----------------------
 1 | ABC   | 1987698.987 |      0  
 2 | DEF   | 1987870.987 |    172
 3 | GHI   | 1987990.987 |    120
 4 | JKL   | 1988200.987 |    210
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: How is that "cumulative"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [prev()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/prevfunction) function, for example

```
datatable(ID:int, NAME:string, Value:double)
 [1, "ABC", 1987698.987,
  2, "DEF", 1987870.987,
  3, "GHI", 1987990.987,
  4, "JKL", 1988200.987]
| order by ID asc 
| extend Cumulative_difference = coalesce(Value - prev(Value), double(0))
```

| ID | NAME | Value | Cumulative_difference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC | 1987698.987 | 0 |
| 2 | DEF | 1987870.987 | 172 |
| 3 | GHI | 1987990.987 | 120 |
| 4 | JKL | 1988200.987 | 210 |

Comment: @anvera thanks you.. What will be the performance impact  if apply this on 1Million  records? Thanks in advance

Comment: It depends how big is your cluster, usually, performance is highly correlated with the number of cores in the cluster. In any case you should give it a try. You can also use the "free cluster" offering and try this there with no hassle.